# JQTouch - links in li not working after scrolling

Tags: html-lists, jqtouch

I have a sorted list using JQTouch. The list contains about 20 li-elements containing different links. The first li's that are on the screen without scrolling are working just fine. But after I scrolled down on my iPhone the links are no longer working.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<ul class="rounded">
<li class="arrow"><a id="1" href="#opdracht">1. Typical Amsterdam</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a id="2" href="#opdracht">2. Route</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a id="3" href="#opdracht">3. Directions</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a id="4" href="#opdracht">4. Shops</a></li>
---
<li class="arrow"><a id="5" href="#opdracht">9. Sightseeing</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a id="6" href="#opdracht">10. Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I hope someone can help me out.

For an example, please visit: http://www.wappdesign.nl/teamuitje on your iPhone and try to visit the link after scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

In `jqtouch.min.js` file

in the 'handleTouch' function there is:

```
startX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX,
startY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY,
```

these lines need to change to:

```
startX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX,
startY = event.changedTouches[0].pageY,
```

Please ref this link
https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/issues/297