# After scroll <ui> list hyperlink not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am facing a very strange problem with  list on my page.
 once my page is loaded(http://olstr.com) everything is fine, but once I scroll the window all hyper links are not working.
I have tried on ipdad, iphone and widows(Chrome) but on IE its working.
but not able to understand what is wrong with Chrome and others.
I have used simple JQuery and JavaScript to create the page.

Please if some have any idea kindly share your thought.
I found [JQTouch - links in li not working after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184859/jqtouch-links-in-li-not-working-after-scrolling) but not able to help for problem.

Comment: Have checked the errors that are logged in console.

Comment: some container is coming on top when scrolled.

Comment: I mean some container is covering the page when scrolled. You should probably check in scroll event of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting your site, you have set `min-height:100%;` in `page-wrap` css class. Once you scrolled the page, then `position: fixed;` is applied to the `page-wrap` div, so it is overlapping the content section. Instead of `100%` use some minimum `px` value.

Comment: Yes might be this issue .after changing the position Fixed I get this problem.

Comment: Hi,thanks for identifying problem..this resolved my issue .thsk again

Comment: @Abhishek I am glad it helped. Mark it as answer if this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with your site. The one I noticed immediately was that the HTML is not well formed - some closing tags are missing. If your HTML is not well formed, you might end up with weird problems like this all the time which can't be fixed simply by tweaking the CSS. Use an HTML validator to make sure that the markup you have generated is correct.

The second problem, I noticed was that some background URLs are empty in the CSS. While this may not have contributed to this problem, it is something you might want to check.

Comment: Thanks Indra for your analysis.